# Type, nature and meaning (What is ) "#call" in c++

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I was trying to study a simple MPI code intended for CUDA. And I encountered this line.

```
cerr << "MPI error calling \""#call"\"\n"; \
```

What is `#call`? Related to CUDA, C++ or MPI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of a macro definition. `call` is a macro parameter, presumably the name of a function. The `#` operator turns its operand into a string. So `#call` is a string with the name of the function.

Adjacent strings are concatenated, so the name will be combined with `"MPI error calling \""` and `"\"\n"` and output on `cerr`.

The `#` operator is part of the C/C++ preprocessor and string literal concatenation is also common to the two languages (but not part of the preprocessor per se). So no, it's not special to CUDA, C++, or MPI.